# Schedule restart of applications on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I want to schedule restart for an app so  is there any way that applications will be restarted automatically after specific timelimit in PCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is anything within PCF that can execute CF Commands. My suggestion is to have a **CI/CD Job Configured** (`Jenkins-Job` for example) that will execute `cf restart <app_name>` at scheduled Intervals

Answer (score -1):

I've been working on a scheduler service which you can register at Cloud Foundry containing service plans also for restarting apps. There are also other service plans like just triggering an arbitrary http-endpoint. I'd be happy if you try it out and provide me feedback. Just check it out in GIT: https://github.com/grimmpp/cloud-foundry-resource-scheduler
I've also started to describe what is provides and how it can be installed and configured. For using it you just need to create service instances in the marketplace of cloud foundry and specify some parameters for e.g. how often or when it should be called. ...